# Regex no imprime si es muy largo

Tags: python, regex

Muy buenas!

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio sobre expresiones regulares: tengo que tomar un texto como este:

> "146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST
> /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622\n197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129
> [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE
> /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HT"

y extraer cierta información con esta forma:

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", "user_name":"feest6811", "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",         "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

Me pongo a extraer las IPs y los nombres de usuario y todo bien. Hago los grupos y genial, todo perfecto.

Es decir, esto me lo ejecuta y funciona a la perfección:

```
for item in re.finditer("(?P<host>\d{3}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{3})(\s[-]\s)(?P<user_name>\w+)", text4):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

El problema es cuando añado a la expresión, la parte de la expresion para sacar la fecha y hora: No me devuelve nada.

He probado creando un patrón y nada.

```
for item in re.finditer("(?P<host>\d{3}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{3})(\s[-]\s)(?P<user_name>\w+)(\d\d[/]\w+[/]\d\w+[:]\d\d[:]\d\d[:]\d\d\s[-]\d{4})", text4, re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

No sé si es porque la expresión es muy larga o que tengo que hacer.

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Pareciera que la linea de log que publicas está incompleta. Faltan un par de valores comparado con la línea previa. ¿No debería terminar con un \n en todo caso?

Answer (score 3):

Las expresiones regulares conviene hacerlas lo más simple y genéricas posibles, porque luego tratar de analizarlas es tarea imposible.

Debe haber un error en tu expresión regular, pero sale más simple reescribirla que tratar de depurarla.

Analizando una línea del texto

```
'146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622',
```

podemos decir que es una colección de valores separados por espacios o otros simbolos. Qué contienen esos valores (letras, dígitos, otros símbolos), es irrelevante.

Entonces, para reconocer la IP y el usuario me basta

en lugar de escribir tan preciso como

```
(?P<host>\d{3}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{3})(\s[-]\s)(?P<user_name>\w+)
```

basta con

```
(?P<host>\S+) - (?P<user_name>\S+)
```

Asi, la expresión necesaria para reconocer todas las partes es:

```
(?P<host>\S+) - (?P<user_name>\S+) \[(?P<dia>[^:]+):(?P<hora>\S+) (?P<zona>\S+)\] (?P<texto>.*) (?P<status>\d+) (?P<size>\d+)
```

Para reconocer la fecha y hora busque dentro de los delimitadores `[]`, pero como tienen significado especial dentro de una expresión regular, los escape anteponiendo `\`.

Para reconocer el día acepte cualquier caracter que no fuera ':', usando la expresión `[^:]`. Ese mismo `:` encontrados es reconocido y descartado por la expresión regular, antes de seguir extrayendo la hora.

Cualquier parte de la expresión regular que no esté encerradas entre `()` es reconocida, pero no captura. A si se descartan las partes no interesantes.

Con la hora no hay problemas, es cualquier caracter no-espacio.

**Demo**

Nota: complete los datos faltantes en la línea 2 de la pregunta original.

```
import re
patron = re.compile("(?P<host>\S+) - (?P<user_name>\S+) \[(?P<dia>[^:]+):(?P<hora>\S+) (?P<zona>\S+)\] (?P<texto>.*) (?P<status>\d+) (?P<size>\d+)")
log = [
'146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622',
'197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HT" 200 10203']

for linea in log:
    m = patron.match(linea)
    if m:
        print(m.groupdict())
```

produce:

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'dia': '21/Jun/2019', 'hora': '15:45:24', 'zona': '-0700', 'texto': '"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"', 'status': '302', 'size': '4622'}
{'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'dia': '21/Jun/2019', 'hora': '15:45:25', 'zona': '-0700', 'texto': '"DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HT"', 'status': '200', 'size': '10203'}
```

Probablemente haya que hacer ajustes para convertir los datos como `dia` y `hora` a otros formatos más útiles.